# Ionic to SVG image not displayed in IOS Devises

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to view a SVG image on my iPhone using Ionic 3. On iOS the svg image is not displayed. But on android devices everything is working well. Anyone know how to fix that issue?

Thanks

I'm using following html code:

```
<svg   [class.checked]="clapIconChecked"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-549 338 100.1 125">
  <path d="M-471.2 366.8c1.2 1.1 1.9 2.6 2.3 4.1.4-.3.8-.5 1.2-.7 1-1.9.7-4.3-1-5.9-2-1.9-5.2-1.9-7.2.1l-.2.2c1.8.1 3.6.9 4.9 2.2zm-28.8 14c.4.9.7 1.9.8 3.1l16.5-16.9c.6-.6 1.4-1.1 2.1-1.5 1-1.9.7-4.4-.9-6-2-1.9-5.2-1.9-7.2.1l-15.5 15.9c2.3 2.2 3.1 3 4.2 5.3zm-38.9 39.7c-.1-8.9 3.2-17.2 9.4-23.6l18.6-19c.7-2 .5-4.1-.1-5.3-.8-1.8-1.3-2.3-3.6-4.5l-20.9 21.4c-10.6 10.8-11.2 27.6-2.3 39.3-.6-2.6-1-5.4-1.1-8.3z"/>
  <path d="M-527.2 399.1l20.9-21.4c2.2 2.2 2.7 2.6 3.5 4.5.8 1.8 1 5.4-1.6 8l-11.8 12.2c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l34-35c1.9-2 5.2-2.1 7.2-.1 2 1.9 2 5.2.1 7.2l-24.7 25.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l28.5-29.3c2-2 5.2-2 7.1-.1 2 1.9 2 5.1.1 7.1l-28.5 29.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.4 1.7 0l24.7-25.3c1.9-2 5.1-2.1 7.1-.1 2 1.9 2 5.2.1 7.2l-24.7 25.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l14.6-15c2-2 5.2-2 7.2-.1 2 2 2.1 5.2.1 7.2l-27.6 28.4c-11.6 11.9-30.6 12.2-42.5.6-12-11.7-12.2-30.8-.6-42.7m18.1-48.4l-.7 4.9-2.2-4.4m7.6.9l-3.7 3.4 1.2-4.8m5.5 4.7l-4.8 1.6 3.1-3.9"/>
</svg>
```

```html
  <span>
<svg   [class.checked]="clapIconChecked"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-549 338 100.1 125"  version="1.1">
  <path d="M-471.2 366.8c1.2 1.1 1.9 2.6 2.3 4.1.4-.3.8-.5 1.2-.7 1-1.9.7-4.3-1-5.9-2-1.9-5.2-1.9-7.2.1l-.2.2c1.8.1 3.6.9 4.9 2.2zm-28.8 14c.4.9.7 1.9.8 3.1l16.5-16.9c.6-.6 1.4-1.1 2.1-1.5 1-1.9.7-4.4-.9-6-2-1.9-5.2-1.9-7.2.1l-15.5 15.9c2.3 2.2 3.1 3 4.2 5.3zm-38.9 39.7c-.1-8.9 3.2-17.2 9.4-23.6l18.6-19c.7-2 .5-4.1-.1-5.3-.8-1.8-1.3-2.3-3.6-4.5l-20.9 21.4c-10.6 10.8-11.2 27.6-2.3 39.3-.6-2.6-1-5.4-1.1-8.3z"/>
  <path d="M-527.2 399.1l20.9-21.4c2.2 2.2 2.7 2.6 3.5 4.5.8 1.8 1 5.4-1.6 8l-11.8 12.2c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l34-35c1.9-2 5.2-2.1 7.2-.1 2 1.9 2 5.2.1 7.2l-24.7 25.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l28.5-29.3c2-2 5.2-2 7.1-.1 2 1.9 2 5.1.1 7.1l-28.5 29.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.4 1.7 0l24.7-25.3c1.9-2 5.1-2.1 7.1-.1 2 1.9 2 5.2.1 7.2l-24.7 25.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l14.6-15c2-2 5.2-2 7.2-.1 2 2 2.1 5.2.1 7.2l-27.6 28.4c-11.6 11.9-30.6 12.2-42.5.6-12-11.7-12.2-30.8-.6-42.7m18.1-48.4l-.7 4.9-2.2-4.4m7.6.9l-3.7 3.4 1.2-4.8m5.5 4.7l-4.8 1.6 3.1-3.9"/>
</svg>

  </span>
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, so i am following this. Btw, did you figured it out it the meanwhile?

Comment: I don't get any solution. i  replaced to image format

Comment: Lol, Ok that is also a way of doing it. Thank you for replying anyway.